# API-only doesn't load JS/CSS assets properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I created an app using api-only flag, and I ran into a problem.

I wanted to install a gem that includes a mountable engine, in which there are JS/CSS assets. When I mounted the engine, I got an error complaining that the JS/CSS files don't exist.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  if Rails.env.development?
    mount SomeGem::Rails::Engine, at: "/some-gem"
  end
end
```

When I tried the same on a new app without the `api-only` flag, it worked great without any hassle. So I am assuming that the `api-only` flag is affecting the bundle process (maybe excluding all JS and CSS assets?) but I can't find the relevant information in the [doc](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html).

What am I missing?

Comment: While I don't know _exactly_ why this happens, I want to point out that the whole meaning of api-only mode is to not include any of the html fluff. One simply doesn't need them in a server that talks json. If you want to install an admin ui (or whatever that engine is), feel free to do this in a sibling full rails app. It is perfectly normal to run two or more apps on the same database.

Comment: While I mostly agree, I think the api server should be able to serve limited views when needed. For example, going to `/rails/info` in an api server renders a view with all the routes.

Comment: I don't think so. Api is for robots. Robots understand json better than arbitrary html (see hypermedia, for example). Api documentation should not live in the api server itself, but in the main app.

Answer (score 0):

Well I haven't tried Rails 5 yet but, my general understanding is that API only will allow developers write business logic and won't work well with the view layer. Hence, I think you have chosen the wrong development mode. I suggest if you need to do view related development then, you should remove the flag and try to use it.